# Using switchMap to trigger repeated HTTP requests on state changes

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I'm working on an Angular project where I'm trying to trigger an HTTP request every time the state of a hot observable changes and subscribe to all of these changes using the switchMap operator. However, I'm facing an issue where the HTTP request is only triggered once. After the first request, the observable keeps returning the same value without making additional HTTP requests.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
  httpClient = inject(HttpClient);
  stateChanges = interval(1000);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getResponse$().subscribe((response) => console.log(response));
  }

  getResponse$(): Observable<any> {
      return this.stateChanges
        .pipe(
          mergeMap(newState => this.httpClient.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'))
        )
  }
```

Is there's a way to force the HTTP request to be sent every time, or is there something I'm doing wrong in my code?

Edit:

The provided solution by @Aqeel Abbas was indeed correct. The issue I was facing with my Angular project was due to my first observer being based on a boolean value. As a result, when the value remained the same, the HTTP request was not being triggered

Comment: The sample code you're sharing does send the http request every 1000ms.

Comment: there could be some kind of pragrammatic cache interceptors which do the caching logic for you, or maybe your query is returned with cache headers and browser caches and reuses the response

Comment: This example is not simplified but most likely not giving the essence of the actual code, since it should (haven't tested) actually send a request every second...

Comment: Could it be that you have a shareReplay after the switchMap/mergeMap and the http-request errors after the first call?

Answer (score 0):

Because switchMap only switches to a new inner observable when the outer observable (stateChanges) emits a new value, the problem you're experiencing, where the HTTP request is only initiated once, is caused by this. StateChanges is a hot observable in your code that emits values every second and was generated by interval(1000). SwitchMap, which is still subscribed to the initial inner observable because it's a continuous stream of values, does not, however, re-trigger the HTTP request because of this.

The switchMap operator should be used in conjunction with a subject or source observable that emits new values when the HTTP request is to be triggered in order to accomplish your purpose. Here is an updated illustration:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css']
           })
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
    httpClient: HttpClient;
    stateChanges = new Subject<void>();

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.httpClient = http;
 }

 ngOnInit() {
     this.getResponse$().subscribe((response) => console.log(response));
  }

  triggerRequest() {
     this.stateChanges.next();
   }

   getResponse$(): Observable<any> {
     return this.stateChanges.pipe(
       switchMap(() => 
     
    this.httpClient.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'))
    );
   }
  }
```

Hope, It helps. you can ask any questions If you face any.

Comment: Can't see how this code answers the OP's question - why is the interval gone? And the explanation given is incorrect - the switchMap *would* issue an request every second.

See there: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-v3hzj7?file=index.ts

Comment: The question also meant that they wanted to "force the HTTP request to be sent every time" so the request is being sent every time. If you find it incorrect you can make changes to it.